# Generalization of binomial coefficients to both non-integer arguments

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, power-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

It is known that binomial coefficients can be generalized to the following: for $s\in\mathbb R$ and $k\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{equation*}
  \binom{s}{k} := \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{s-i}{k-i} = \frac{s(s-1) \cdots(s-k+1)}{k !} = \frac{(s)_k}{k !} = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(s-k+1)k !},
\end{equation*}
where $(s)_k := s(s-1) \cdots (s-k+1)$ denotes the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). For the generalized binomial coefficients, the following [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) holds:
\begin{equation*}
  (1+x)^s = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s}{k} x^k.
\end{equation*}

It is natural to further generalize to the case where two arguments are both non-integers in the following way: for $s,p\in\mathbb R$,
\begin{equation*}
  \binom{s}{p} := \prod_{i=0}^{\lceil p \rceil-1} \frac{s-i}{p-i} = \frac{(s)_{\lceil p \rceil}}{(p)_{\lceil p \rceil}} = \frac{\Gamma(s+1) \Gamma(p-\lceil p \rceil+1)}{\Gamma(s-\lceil p \rceil+1) \Gamma(p+1)}.
\end{equation*}
But for such a generalization, do we have the counterpart of the binomial theorem? What is the following series: for $0<p<1$,
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s}{k+p} x^k = ?
\end{equation*}
Or is there a good definition for $\binom{s}{k+p}$ so that the above series can have a meaning?

TIA...

Comment: I think that the generalization your are talking about is not very natural. A more natural option is to just use the gamma function, without any ceiling functions. $\binom{n}{k}:=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for your comment. Could the option you provide give a formula to the series at the end of my question?

Answer (score 1):

Defined $\binom{\alpha}{\beta}:=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\beta+1)\Gamma(\alpha-\beta+1)}$, the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s}{k+p}z^k$ is a [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) one, and has a closed form in terms of the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) (elementary if $s$ and $p$ are half-integers).

Indeed, with $\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$ the (complete) beta function, write
$$
\binom{s}{k+p}=\frac{\mathrm{B}(p,k+1)}{\mathrm{B}(p,s-p+1)}\binom{s-p}{k};
$$
then for $\Re p>0$ and $0<|z|<1$ we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s}{k+p}z^k
&=\frac1{\mathrm{B}(p,s-p+1)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s-p}{k}z^k\int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^k\,dt\\
&=\frac1{\mathrm{B}(p,s-p+1)}\int_0^1 t^{p-1}\big(1+z(1-t)\big)^{s-p}\,dt\\
&=\boxed{z^{-p}(1+z)^s I_{z/(1+z)}(p,s-p+1)}
\end{align*}
(the principal branches taken). Note also that, after $t=\frac{(1+z)x}{1+zx}$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s}{k+p}z^k=\frac{(1+z)^s}{\mathrm{B}(p,s-p+1)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{p-1}\,dx}{(1+zx)^{s+1}},
$$
leading to $\mathrm{B}(-z;p,-s)$. All these things get analytically continued easily.